# code not working, jcepopup window not reloading while closing

Tags: javascript, joomla2.5, chronoforms

I'm having a problem with a form. I need to perform a query once a jcepopup window has closed, but so far i can't make it work. I tried the following code:

```
function passVal(val1,val2){
  parent.document.getElementById('award_number').value=val1;
  parent.document.getElementById('award_name').value=val2;
  parent.document.getElementById('aw_number').value=val1;
  parent.document.getElementById('aw_name').value=val2;
  window.onunload = refreshParent;
  window.parent.jcepopup.close();
}

window.onunload = refreshParent;
    function refreshParent() {
        window.opener.location.reload();
    }
```

However, so far it's not working, at least not the reload part. It returns the values, but i can't use them to trigger the next query that i would like to use.

Anyway, I'm open to suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the MDN docs which state:

> You can and should handle this event through window.addEventListener() and the unload event. More documentation is available there.

```
window.addEventListener('unload', function () { console.log('do stuff'); } );
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onunload